# How to use a Parameter in calculated field defined in getFields() (Google Data Studio Community Connector)?

Tags: looker-studio

In order to get a correct date difference in days from today, I need to specify the time zone in the `today()` function.
I can easily do that adding a calculated field in the user interface, but I could not find a way to use the parameter in a calculated field when it's defined in the connector schema within the `getFields()` function.
As in this example (that does not work) where `timezone` is a parameter, defined in `getConfig()`:

```
fields.newDimension()
    .setId('daysToArrival')
    .setDescription('Days from today to arrival')
    .setFormula('DATE_DIFF(arrival,TODAY(timezone))')
    .setType(types.NUMBER)
```

**Image of the parameter duly appearing in the datasource**:
[image: image of the parameter duly appearing in the datasource]

Apparently the parameter `timezone` is correctly passed along in the `request`:

```
{ fields: [ { name: 'arrival' }, { name: 'number' }, { name: 'status' } ],
  configParams: 
   { timezone: '+1',
     dataset: 'booking',
     server: 'sky-eu1'},
  dateRange: { endDate: '2021-04-12', startDate: '2021-03-16' },
  scriptParams: { lastRefresh: '1618343639295' },
  dimensionsFilters: [ [ [Object] ] ] }
```

Comment: Have you tried `.setFormula('DATE_DIFF(arrival,TODAY(request.configParams.timezone))')`? Assuming in the config, you are requesting a `timezone` input.

Comment: @MinhazKazi Hi Minhaz, your help is greatly appreciated - as I very much valued your tutorials. Alas, it didn't work, I get a system error: Sorry, we encountered an error and were unable to complete your request. Error ID: 7f1c96e1

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. Feedback from users like you make our day! Sorry it seems I made a mistake in my comment and @diego-queiroz posted the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution proposed by @MinhazKazi in the comments is correct, but he forgot some apostrophes.

```
.setFormula('DATE_DIFF(arrival, TODAY("' + request.configParams.timezone + '"))')
```